# Reading in HDF5 file with multiprocessing very slow

Tags: python, multiprocessing, hdf5

I am training a neural network, with data that is too large to fit in memory. I have split the data into chunks in HDF5 format, and am reading them in one at a time, and making them into a generator that I am then feeding in as input to the neural network. I have noticed that reading in the chunks of data is also a bottleneck, and to make this faster, while the network is training on a chunk of data, I am trying to use another process to read in the next chunk of data. My function for reading in the data is below:

```
import h5py 
def get_data(filename):
    current_file = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
    images = current_file['images'].value 
    coords = current_file['coords'].value
    current_file.close()
    return images, coords
```

When I apply this function directly, it works just fine, and reads in the data after around ~45 seconds:

```
import time 
start = time()
images, coords = get_data('Single-Cell-Image-Chunks/0.hdf5')
print(time() - start)
```

However, when I try using a multiprocessing worker, it did not finish after 10 minutes, and I killed it:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
start = time()
pool = Pool(1)
res = pool.apply_async(get_data, ('Single-Cell-Image-Chunks/0.hdf5',))
images, coords = res.get()
print(time() - start)
```

Comment: Is that the actual code that took 10 minutes, or is it being run in parallel with memory/disk intensive processing code?

Comment: That is the actual code. I was not running anything else along with it.